# Sending data to server URL thru JSON

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

hi im new to AsyncTask and i need to send data to API server. im doing the connection and im stuck here. i read about the AsyncTask and this is the code that i've seen. first thing is if i determine if the device is connected, it will send data on the URL given, else. it will send thru SMS

```
public class SendData extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Boolean> {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    String datefinal = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.212/mobile_alerts_api.php?location=&msg=&datetime=&id=";


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try{
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you have not heard of Retrofit or Volley, have you?

Comment: Anyways, I don't think `HttpGet` is the correct class if you want to use a POST

Comment: @cricket_007 yes i never heard of it atm

Comment: Might want to read the documentation for a bit. https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html You're looking for a `JsonObjectRequest` class

Comment: @cricket_007 okay thanks

Comment: Please note that the HttpEntity and related Apache classes are "deprecated" to Android. HttpURLConnection is the Java built-in class for HTTP usage. Volley or Okhttp3 are easy libraries to send String/JSON data. Use Retrofit if you additionally need to parse JSON into/from actual Java objects

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
```

instead of

```
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(url);
```

Get is used to get data from the server. Post is used to send data to the server

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, i need to send data from android app to URL server.

Comment: Refer: https://www.go4expert.com/articles/step-step-guide-sending-data-android-t30182/

Comment: hi, thank you for this

Comment: i cant implement due to conflicts, but thank you for the suggestion. much appreciated

Comment: This doesn't show any JSON

Answer (score 0):

```
        String json=yourJsonData;
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(se);
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Then execute the httppost in your async task class